# Regex and capturing parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, parentheses, capturing-group

I'm trying to understand how capturing parenthesis work for regex but I don't get it...

My code was :

> ```
>    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ab");
>    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("abc");
>
>   while (m.find()) { 
>       for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
>           System.out.println(m.group(i));
>       }
>   }
> ```

so i had no display at all.
What i understood was that i need a capturing parenthesis to remember the matching result and to display it.

So i did :

> ```
>    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ab)");
>    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("abc");
> ```

And i had the expected display : ab

Then i wanted to remember and display only a part of the matching result, so i did :

> ```
>    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a)b");
>    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("abc");
> ```

I was expecting to have : a, but i had : ab

why ?

Answer (score 3):

From the javadocs of [`Matcher#group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-):

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at **one**. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

The problem is that the group zero (i.e. `m.group(0)`) matches the *entire* pattern, not the one inside capturing parentheses. So to match the group you want, you need to start at index 1 and end until the group count:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i));
}
```

In your case, you have only one group. But if you have something like `Pattern.compile("(a)(b)")`, then `(a)` would match group 1 and `(b)` would match group 2.